# Parallel L-C circuit powered by an AC generator

Tags: resonance

I'm trying to understand how LC resonant circuits work, but no explanation I find on the web helps me with that.

The way I understand it is that if I had only an ideal inductive load, as soon as the voltage was applied on the coil by the generator, the coil would produce a counter EMF that would be almost equal in size but opposite to the applied voltage, reducing in magnitude over time. So the current is limited due to the nature of the coil. We find that current lags behind the applied voltage by 90°.

Now the generator has to constantly push the inductive load that is pushing back. This creates power loss.

But if we connect a capacitor parallel to a coil, the current generated by the coils magnetic field flows into a capacitor instead of pushing back on the generator. After the magnetic field is gone, the capacitor would discharge into the coil. Hence the generator is not having to deal with this reactive power, so total power losses (ignoring power losses in the cables due to the reactive current) are lower. This is only true ofcourse if the capacitor and the coil are able to store the same amount of energy at the operating frequency.

As soon as one is bigger then the other, that additional created emf has to be opposed by the generator, where before it didn't have to deal with it.

**This is why if we balance capacitive and inductive effects inside a circuit, we get bigger currents to be used for doing work like in induction heating aparatuses with the same coil resistance and applied voltage.**

Is my picture correct?

Comment: It's like a pendulum - once set in motion only minute energy is needed to keep it swinging back and forth at same amplitude.

Comment: This didn't answer my question. I'm asking about the effect on the generator. Why are we able to get a lot more current, if we put the right sized capacitor parallel to the coil. I know that the magnetization energy is being saved by flowing into a capacitor. But what exactly is preventing the generator from supplying the current to a coil for doing work (let's say magnetic induction in a metal). Is it all about the counter emf produced by reactive elements? Does it create a power loss apart from increased Joule losses?

Comment: It does explain it but you are fixated in some area of thinking that is incorrect. For instance you say "this creates power loss". It doesn't create any power loss - what is pushed in gets pushed back out again. So for a generator feeding a perfect LC there is no energy given to the circuit except during the start up transient duration - this settles down to zero (or very nearly zero) just like a pendulum. If you try and take power from an LC then you have to put power in to compensate. There is no magic bullet.

Comment: This is why I'm asking this question, but you aren't addresing my points. This leads to my confusion. So if there is no power loss created by this, why are we able to get a lot bigger currents when compensating reactive power and so do a lot more work? I'm talking for instance about induction heating. If we didn't add capacitors, the current would be very low and no work could be done. I hope you can explain why this is so. reciprocal energy exchange doesn't explain that.

Comment: Current lags 90 degree in an inductor and leads 90 degrees in a capacitor - vector wise they cancel each other out. At resonance their impedances are equal. Its only when you add **resistance** to the circuit do you get a real *component* of current - 0 degrees and heat energy is produced. In Andy's analogy this is the equivalent of having rusty pivots (frictional loss) on the swing.

Comment: I know all of that. I asked a question in this particular way because I wanted to provoke answers you wouldn't give if I explained things normaly. I would appreciate it if you could actualy address why we can't reach big currents to do work (yes, you put metal in a magnetic field of a coil and it does work, so this puts resistance in the circuit) if we don't add reactive compensation to the circuit (capacitor). Without reactive compensation we might get 10 A, while if we add capacitor we get 100 A on the same resistive load. This is my question. What you're explaining I already know.

Comment: Parts of your picture are correct, but they are resting on a very shaky foundation of sand. Try getting a simulator like LTSpice, and playing with an AC generator with capacitor and/or inductor loads, to see what happens with voltage or current. Try to predict what's going to happen, then simulate and see, then try to understand why it did or didn't. Add resistance to make inductir or generator non-perfect, and simulate again. The problem with induction heating is the practicalities of non-perfect generator losses, not fundamentals.

Comment: @MaDrung a perfect example of wrong thinking in your last comment. If you have a fixed ac voltage on an inductor and an inductively coupled resistive load took 10 amps then adding a capacitor would not change this. You might find that the input current from the source reduced to maybe 50% (or even lower) BUT you wouldn't get 100 amps flowing in the inductively coupled resistive load. You are carrying with you a bunch of mis-concepts that makes talking with you a bad experience because you appear to be too aggressive and I can tell you that your frustration is due to your wrong thinking.

Comment: Could it be that the reason why current decreases in the induction heating aparatus when we're increasing the frequency is because the capacitors in the half-bridge can't fill up in time of one period? The fact is that at high frequency, the current gets really low and near the resonance it gets huge so a lot of power is being drawn while operating at the same voltage. And that example was exageration. But the difference is noticable. Why that difference happens is the core of my question. No answer yet to that question. :/

Comment: I have no idea. No schematic usually means no idea.

Comment: As it is explained in all the books I've read, if the capacitor is just the right size compared to the coil at a specific frequency, the reactive components of the resistance will cancel themselves out, which leads to  there being only a real part of resistance. This is why current increases dramaticaly. since inductive and capacitive reactance cancel eachothers out. But the confusion I have with this is because they are not even real resistances, neither they are creating real losses. I want to understand it in physical terms, step by step including back emf and so on. :P

Comment: How I think it Works is that the coil and capacitor create back emf towards the generator, so the current is smaller. But when you match the capacitor to the coil that back emf is directed towards eachother, leaving the generator voltage "unopposed". Is this the reason the generator can now push high current trough the inductor that is actualy then doing work in the metal being heated by inductors alternating magnetic field? Because capacitor soaks up the back emf from the coil, and coil does the same for capacitor half a period later and the generator is then free to do the work in metal. :D

Comment: If you have a constant alternating voltage across the coil then the coil current is determined by that voltage amplitude, frequency and the inductance. IT MAKES NO DIFFERENCE to the coil current if you resonate the circuit with a capacitor - the coil current remains THE SAME. The generator CANNOT "push high current trough the inductor". It would break the laws of physics. Now go do some studying and stop trying to assert something that is WRONG.